# Increasing character limit for database tables

Tags: database, upgrade, magento2.2.3, table, name

I have recently upgraded a copy of my site from 2.2.5 to version 2.3. All appeared to work correctly however I have encountered issues with a third party extension for a payment gateway.

The extension developer has informed me that recent changes in 2.3 mean that our prefix is causing the end of the table names to be truncated .

I have tried removing the Prefix but this has caused me a lot of issues, so I would rather avoid this if I can.

The developer also informed me that apparently Magento have recently accepted a proposed change to increase this limit and it would be released at some point in the future.

However, having no idea how long this may take I was wandering if anyone can tell me how this limit can be increased?

Where do I need to go in the Magento code?

Thanks in advance :)